# Implementing indian algorithm inside a 'while loop'. What did I do wrong?

Tags: c, recursion

I'm told to implement the function inside the while loop instead of recursive function. And so far I've always got wrong answer. Any indicator on where I made the mistake would be appreciated.
I'm trying to calculate 2^12, but so far whenever I run the program it gives me 4. The original problem then I created this thread is already solved. But I have a new problem which is related to the previous one, but need a different approach

```
#include <stdio.h>

double powerloop(double x, int y, double help)
{
   while(y!=0)
   {
     if((y%2)==0)
     {
        x=x*x;
        y=y/2;
     }

     if((y%2)==1)
     {
        help=help*x;
        x=x*x;
        y=(y-1)/2;
     }

     if(y==1)
     {
       x=x*help;
     }

     return x;
  }
}

int main(void){
     printf("Using powerloop to calculate 2^12: %f \n", powerloop(2, 12, 1));
     return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you tell us exactly what the problem is? Is the output not what you expect? Does it crash? Does it wisper dangerous thoughts into the back of your mind? If you can provide us with more details, we can probably help you a little better.

Comment: Whenever I tried to execute it, the terminal keeps telling me 'Segmentation fault (core dumped)'. The purpose of this program is to provide an efficient way of calculating x^y by using indian algorithm

Comment: Yes. sorry for that. At this point I'm about to give up.

Comment: Yeah, i got no stack and no thread. not sure what does it meant though

Comment: You have now edited the Question so that all traces of the original bug(s) are gone.  Make it kind of useless ... doesn't it.  Voting to close.

Comment: @StephenC or revert the edit

Answer (score 5):

Two issues:

**1.** The following test is wrong:

```
if(y & 2 == 0)
```

You want

```
if((y % 2) == 0)
```

The modulo % operator is not quite the same as doing a "bitwise and" with 2.

**2.** The initial line

```
 double num=power(x, y/2);
```

causes a stack overflow. in Visual C++ it also gives me a clear warning: "C4717: 'power': Recursive for all control paths"

**Recursion always and absolutely needs an end condition where is stops**.

The first thing you do in power() is to call power() again, and again, and again, ...., and again:

```
double power(double x, int y) { 
    double num=power(x, y/2);    // <- call myself again forever
    // other code
 }
```

Since there is no stop condition linked to that call, you will be calling power() forever - or until the always limited call stack is finally exhausted.

Remember that at the very least the return address from each call to power() is stored onto the stack. Compare your implementation with the correct algorithm. You will find that this first call is not made there, and instead it more looks like this:

```
double power(double x, int y)
{

   if(x==0) {   
        return 0;  // stops recursion
   }

    if(y==0) {   
        return 1;    // stops recursion 
    }

    if( (y % 2) == 0) {
        num=num*num;
        y=y/2;
        return num;     // stops recursion
    }

    num=x*power(x, y-1);   // another recursive call
    y=y-1;
    return num;
 }
```

Comment: Yeah that doesn't work either. It still give me:     Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Comment: Was just about to post the recursion problem as the primary issue.  The modulus operator syntax is another one.

Comment: not sure what does it meant by causing stack overflow. I'm quite new at programming unfortunately

Comment: [This link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_overflow#Infinite_recursion) is especially for you :-)

Comment: i've read the link but isn't it how I supposed to do it? On my instruction sheet it is said  "The function 'power' should be recursive (by nature of the algorithm)." Why is it getting complicated. I don't remembered being taught this stuff

Comment: I added some more info.

Comment: Hi JensG,  just read what you added. it's crystal clear now! thanksssssssssss!

Answer (score 3):

Your having infinite recursion

```
double power(double x, int y) { 
    double num=power(x, y/2); 
    /* .... */
 }
```

power() will unconditionally call itself. I didn't check the algorithm itself but you need some check there ...

Answer (score 1):

Undoubtedly, you're suffering a stack overflow.

The lines:

```
double power(double x, int y)
{
   double num=power(x, y/2);
```

Result in `power` calling `power` calling `power` calling `power`... with no chance to ever return.

Each time you call a function, the return address is pushed on to the stack. You keep doing this and with no `return`s to pop addresses from the stack, you eventually run out of space and get a segfault.

What's missing is your termination condition in this recursive algorithm, i.e. the code path that is executed that does *not* result in a recursive path.

Comment: I thought the condition y==1, then return 1 is the termination?

Comment: You don't have any lines that contain `y==1`

Comment: Sorry i meant y==0, if y==1 it will get subtracted by 1 and ended being a zero, when it's zero it's supposed to terminate

Comment: OK. Well, you *always* make a call to `power` as your first line of `power`; there is no way for `power` to ever `return`... leading to your stack overflow.

Comment: You never get to execute any of your `if` statements.

Comment: Thank you very much for making me realise that I have edited the code and have run properly. I tested it by using 2^12 and it delivers the right result.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you call power (3.0, 10).

The first thing your function does is to call power (3.0, 5).

The first thing that call does is to call power (3.0, 2).

The first thing that call does is to call power (3.0, 1).

The first thing that call does is to call power (3.0, 0).

The first thing that call does is to call power (3.0, 0).

The first thing that call does is to call power (3.0, 0).

The first thing that call does is to call power (3.0, 0).

The first thing that call does is to call power (3.0, 0).

The first thing that call does is to call power (3.0, 0).

...

A few million calls later you get a "Segmentation fault".

Comment: I finally realised that. Thank you. I have fixed it

Answer (score 1):

Your `return x` should be inside the scope of the last `if` statement.